# ajax problema envio de datos con formdata

Tags: php, ajax

No logro que el formulario imprima los datos en el div "resp" que agrupo en la variable "form_data", esto es un codigo de prueba que estoy haciendo para aprender a usar mejor formData.

```
<?php
 $mes = "marzo";
?> 

<script>
var tiempo = "llueve";
$(document).on('ready',function(){

  $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
    var url = "datos.php";
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("usuario", usuario);
    form_data.append("contrasena", contrasena);
    form_data.append("mes", mes);
    form_data.append("tiempo", tiempo);                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: form_data,
       success: function(data)            
       {
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

```
<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mes" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>">
    <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
</form>
<div id="resp"></div>
```

datos.php

```
<?php   
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña  = $_POST['contrasena'];
$mes  = $_POST['mes'];
$tiempo  = $_POST['tiempo'];
echo "tu usuario es: ".$usuario." contraseña es: ".$contraseña." y el mes es ".$mes" ,tambien ".$tiempo; 
?>
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, aclara que queres decir con que no logras que los muestre. Tira algun error?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que he observado en tu código es que no estás llenando el FormData con la información del formulario, estás usando variables que parecen estar indefinidas.
Yo le asignaría ids a los campos del formulario en html:

```
<form method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mes" id="mes" value="<?php echo $mes; ?>">
    <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
</form>
```

Cambiaría la parte del js así ya que no se están tomando los valores del form:

```
<script>
var tiempo = "llueve";
$(document).on('ready',function(){

  $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
    var url = "datos.php";
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("usuario", $("#usuario").val());
    form_data.append("contrasena", $("#contrasena").val());
    form_data.append("mes", $("#mes").val());
    form_data.append("tiempo", tiempo);                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: form_data,
       success: function(data)            
       {
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo en tu codigo es que te hace falta indicar de que parte estas tomando las valores para que te los envie por ajax

intenta esto

```
<script>
var tiempo = "llueve";
$(document).on('ready',function(){

$('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
var url = "datos.php";
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("usuario",$('#usuario').val());
form_data.append("contrasena",$('#contrasena').val());
form_data.append("mes", $('#mes').val());
form_data.append("tiempo", tiempo);                                      

$.ajax({                        
   type: "POST",                 
   url: url,                    
   data: form_data,`introducir el código aquí`
   success: function(data)            
   {
     $('#resp').html(data);           
   }
 });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Con `var url = "datos.php";` guarda la dirección en la variable  `url` y luego la pasa a a la propiedad `url` de `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que no estas declarando la propiedad processData

```
               $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              data:formData,
              processData: false,  //importante cuando se utiliza el objeto formData
              url:"",
              success:function(r){
                datos  = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
                console.log(datos); 
              }
            });
```